# NGINX. Load balancing between OpenShift clusters. How get name of server under upstream?

Tags: nginx, openshift

I have application that works on two OpenShift clusters and I want to use Nginx (free) for load balancing.

My OS routes use Passthrought termination type, so I need pass ssl_name and Host headers to resolve services.

Part of my Nginx conf:

```
upstream backend {
    server.com.one
    server.com.two max_fails ...
}

server {
    ...
    proxy_ssl_name $proxy_host;
    proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
    proxy_pass https://backend;
}
```

Variable $proxy_host return **backend**, not **server.com.one** or **server.com.two**.

How can I get server name under upstream?
Maybe I can pass something like concatenation of two servers in proxy_ssl_name?

Other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap every upstream to intermediate server block:

```
upstream backend {
    # server.com.one
    127.127.0.1:2000;
    # server.com.two
    127.127.0.2:2000 max_fails ...;
}

server {
    proxy_pass https://backend;
}

server {
    listen 127.127.0.1:2000;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://server.com.one;
    }
}

server {
    listen 127.127.0.2:2000;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://server.com.two;
    }
}
```